# Android Studio freezing when editing layouts with preview open?

Tags: xml, layout, android-studio, freeze, editing

Just recently my Android Studio(latest version 1.4.1 and previous version too) seems to be freezing when ever I edit a layout. The process when it's recalculating my changes it just straight up freezes. The only workaround for it is just to close the preview window when editing my layout and then reopen it to view my changes.

The freeze happens on and off, it doesn't happen all the time.
Is this a problem for anyone else? any better solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Happens to me too, with i3 processor and 8 GB or RAM. Don't know how to get rid of this.

Comment: It disappeared for me..i had it for a bout a good 3-4 days, then this week it hasn't happened at all.

Comment: Maybe it's a sickness :P, will wait and see.

Comment: Same here. Been fine for a while and now it freezes. I have to close it with task manager and then start up all over again.

Comment: same issue for me as well, did you guys find any solution or workaround...?

Answer (score 2):

Had similar experience on android studio 2.3, solved it by opening Tasking manager and checking for git for windows process and ending the task. noticed that once memory usage for this task gets above 300mb, android studio begins to hang

Answer (score 0):

One cause of this can be a layout that inflates itself recursively.

If you are editing a custom component and you make a call to inflate the layout from within the code while also having the root element of the layout file set to your component's name, then this will happen. There are a few ways to solve it:

**Solution 1**

Make sure to put your inflation call inside a check for edit mode:

```
if(!view.isInEditMode()) 
{
    // inflate
}
```

**Solution 2**

Don't use your component name as the root element in the layout file for the component if you are inflating in the code.

**Solution 3**

Remove your inflation code and move your logic to

```
@Override
public void onFinishInflate()
```

Answer (score -1):

This below command helped me to fix the freezing issue:

```
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
```